# Как при UI тестировании проверить выполнение запроса к серверу?

Tags: android, android-testing

В проекте подключен `Dagger 2` и реализовано `MVP`. Для `UI` тестирования используется `Espresso` + `Cocumber`. В одном из тестов вводится логин и пароль, далее нажимается кнопка войти и выполняется запрос авторизации. После нужно протестировать, что авторизация прошла успешно. Вопрос, как правильно при `UI` тестировании, работать с сетевыми запросами? Подменить реализацию `ApiHelper` или как то ожидать в тесте выполнения запроса? Примеры не помешают.

Comment: Подменяйте конечно. Вы же UI тестируете, а не авторизацию.

Comment: @eugeneek На официальном сайте предлагается использовать IdlingResource https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource.html